# Find sum across varying no of columns

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I have table such  that :

```
value1   value2     value3    value4    value5   constant
1          2          3           4         5     2
8          2          8           3         5     2
1          5          3           4         5     3
1          2          6           4         5     3
```

Now what i want to do is ,i want to find the sum across the columns for only those number of columns as the value given in constant field:

for example in row1 if the constant value is `2`,
i need to find the sum of `value1+value2`.

If the value in constant was `3`, i need to find the sum `value 1+ value2 + value3`

Sorry for the bad english.What is suitable way to do it? i have been googling it for a while ow but couldn't find of a suitable way

Comment: This could prove useful: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html

Comment: I (very, very strongly) suspect 'what you want to do' is to normalize your data!

Comment: @Strawberry i tried but , this is the required format

Comment: For storing data? No it isn't. Perhaps you're confusing data storage with data retrieval and display. THIS IS DEFINITELY THE WRONG WAY

Comment: I agree with Strawberry definitely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Intro**

The normal way to resolve this question is: chose correct structure. If you have 24 fields and you need to loop dynamically in SQL, then *something went wrong*. Also, it is bad that your table has not any primary key (or you've not mentioned that).

**Extremely important note**

It is no matter that the way I'll describe will work. It is still bad practice because of using some special things in MySQL. You can use it on your own risk - and, again, reconsider your structure if it's possible.

**The hack**

Actually, you *can* do some tricks using MySQL [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html) tables. With this you can create "text" SQL, which later can be used in [prepared statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

*My table*

It's called `test`. Here it is:

```
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| value1   | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| value2   | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| value3   | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| value4   | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| constant | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

-I have `4` "value" fields in it and *no primary key* column (that causes troubles, but I've resolved that). Now, my data:

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+
| value1 | value2 | value3 | value4 | constant |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+
|      2 |      5 |      6 |      0 |        2 |
|      1 |   -100 |      0 |      0 |        1 |
|      3 |     10 |    -10 |      0 |        3 |
|      4 |      0 |     -1 |      5 |        3 |
|     -1 |      1 |     -1 |      1 |        4 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+
```

*The trick*

It's about selecting data from mentioned service schema in MySQL and working with [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function:

```
select 
  concat('SELECT CASE(seq) ', 
    group_concat(groupcase separator ''), 
    ' END AS result FROM (select *, @j:=@j+1 as seq from test cross join (select @j:=0) as initj) as inittest') 
from 
  (select 
    concat(' WHEN ', rownum, ' THEN ', groupvalue) as groupcase 
   from 
     (select 
       rownum, 
       group_concat(COLUMN_NAME SEPARATOR '+') as groupvalue 
      from 
       (select 
         *, 
         @row:=@row+1 as rownum 
        from test 
          cross join (select @row:=0) as initrow) as tablestruct 
        left join 
          (select 
             COLUMN_NAME, 
             @num:=@num+1 as num 
           from 
             INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS cross join (select @num:=0) as init 
           where 
             TABLE_SCHEMA='test' && 
             TABLE_NAME='test' && 
             COLUMN_NAME!='constant') as struct 
          on tablestruct.constant>=struct.num 
        group by 
          rownum) as groupvalues) as groupscase
```

-what will this do? Actually, I recommend to execute it step-by-step (i.e. add more complex layer to that which you've already understood) - I doubt there's short way to describe what's happening. It's not a wizardry, it's about constructing valid text SQL from input conditions. End result will be like:

```
SELECT CASE(seq)  WHEN 1 THEN value1+value2 WHEN 2 THEN value1 WHEN 3 THEN value3+value2+value1 WHEN 4 THEN value3+value2+value1 WHEN 5 THEN value2+value1+value4+value3 END AS result FROM (select *, @j:=@j+1 as seq from test cross join (select @j:=0) as initj) as inittest
```

(I didn't add formatting because that SQL is *generated* string, not the one you'll write by yourself).

*Last step*

What now? Just Allocate it with:

```
mysql> set @s=(select concat('SELECT CASE(seq) ', group_concat(groupcase separator ''), ' END AS result FROM (select *, @j:=@j+1 as seq from test cross join (select @j:=0) as initj) as inittest') from (select concat(' WHEN ', rownum, ' THEN ', groupvalue) as groupcase from (select rownum, group_concat(COLUMN_NAME SEPARATOR '+') as groupvalue from (select *, @row:=@row+1 as rownum from test cross join (select @row:=0) as initrow) as tablestruct left join (select COLUMN_NAME, @num:=@num+1 as num from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS cross join (select @num:=0) as init where TABLE_SCHEMA='test' && TABLE_NAME='test' and COLUMN_NAME!='constant') as struct on tablestruct.constant>=struct.num group by rownum) as groupvalues) as groupscase);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> prepare stmt from @s;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Statement prepared
```

-and, finally:

```
mysql> execute stmt;
```

You'll get results as:

```
+--------+
| result |
+--------+
|      7 |
|      1 |
|      3 |
|      3 |
|      0 |
+--------+
```

**Why is this bad**

Because it generates string for whole table. I.e. *for each row*! Imagine if you'll have 1000 rows - that will be nasty. MySQL also has limitation in `GROUP_CONCAT`: [group_concat_max_len](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) - which will limit this way, obviously.

*So why I did that?*

Because I was curious if the way without additional DDL and implicit recounting of table's fields exist. I've found it, so leaving it here.

Answer (score 3):

value column is fixed from 1 to 5? if not you need to generate dynamic query.

try this:

```
SELECT
  IF(constant = 1, value1, 
    IF (constant = 2, value1 + value2,
      IF (constant = 3, value1 + value2 + value3,
        IF (constant = 4, value1 + value2 + value3 + value4, value1 + value2 + value3 + value4 + value5)
      )
    )
  )
FROM tab;
```

**UPDATED**

if i were  you, i'll design like this.

```
tbl1(id, constant),
value_tbl1(tbl1_id, column_seq, value);

SELECT SUM(value)
FROM tbl1 t, value_tbl1 v
WHERE t.id = v.tbl1_id
  AND column_seq BETWEEN 1 AND tbl1.constant
```

Comment: the values in the constant column are not fixed,the above was just an example

Comment: there are 24 value columns

Answer (score 1):

The correct approach might go something like this...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS variables;

CREATE TABLE variables
(constant_id INT NOT NULL
,sequence_id INT NOT NULL
,value INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(constant_id,sequence_id)
);

INSERT INTO variables VALUES
(1,1,1),
(1,2,2),
(1,3,3),
(1,4,4),
(1,5,5),
(2,1,8),
(2,2,2),
(2,3,8),
(2,4,3),
(2,5,5),
(3,1,1),
(3,2,5),
(3,3,3),
(3,4,4),
(3,5,5),
(4,1,1),
(4,2,2),
(4,3,6),
(4,4,4),
(4,5,5);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS constants;

CREATE TABLE constants
(constant_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,constant INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO constants VALUES (1,2),(2,2),(3,3),(4,3);

SELECT * FROM constants;
+-------------+----------+
| constant_id | constant |
+-------------+----------+
|           1 |        2 |
|           2 |        2 |
|           3 |        3 |
|           4 |        3 |
+-------------+----------+

SELECT * FROM variables;
+-------------+-------------+-------+
| constant_id | sequence_id | value |
+-------------+-------------+-------+
|           1 |           1 |     1 |
|           1 |           2 |     2 |
|           1 |           3 |     3 |
|           1 |           4 |     4 |
|           1 |           5 |     5 |
|           2 |           1 |     8 |
|           2 |           2 |     2 |
|           2 |           3 |     8 |
|           2 |           4 |     3 |
|           2 |           5 |     5 |
|           3 |           1 |     1 |
|           3 |           2 |     5 |
|           3 |           3 |     3 |
|           3 |           4 |     4 |
|           3 |           5 |     5 |
|           4 |           1 |     1 |
|           4 |           2 |     2 |
|           4 |           3 |     6 |
|           4 |           4 |     4 |
|           4 |           5 |     5 |
+-------------+-------------+-------+

SELECT c.constant_id
     , SUM(v.value) 
  FROM constants c 
  JOIN variables v 
    ON v.constant_id = c.constant_id 
   AND v.sequence_id <= c.constant 
 GROUP 
    BY c.constant_id;
+-------------+--------------+
| constant_id | SUM(v.value) |
+-------------+--------------+
|           1 |            3 |
|           2 |           10 |
|           3 |            9 |
|           4 |            9 |
+-------------+--------------+
```